# Adding space in Java

Tags: java, char, letter

So I am trying to practice figure out the quickest and easiest way to add spaces in between the character values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {      
        char arr[] = {'g', 'a', 'p', 'e', 't'};
        
        System.out.println("Array: " + new String(arr)); //expected g a p e t
                                                         //instead I got gapet
    }
```

I tried converting the char values as a string, but I still can't figure out to add spaces in between each letter.

Comment: One way: `System.out.println("Array: " + String.join(" ", new String(arr).split("")))` Convert to a string then split into an array of strings because [`String.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) won't accept a char array.

Comment: `System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(arr).replaceAll("[\\[\\],]", ""));`

Comment: If any of the answers below have fixed your problem, please press the checkmark beside indicating the answer that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approaches.

The simplest would be to use a *for-loop*.

```java
String string = "";
int index = 0;
for (char character : arr) {
    if (index++ != 0) string += " ";
    string += character;
}
```

Or, as others have mentioned, you can use the *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))* method, and then use the *[String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...))* method.

```java
String string = String.join(" ", new String(arr).split(""));
```

You could, also, use a *[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)*, utilizing the *[insert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,char))* method.

```java
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder(new String(arr));
for (int index = string.length() - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    string.insert(index, ' ');
```

Finally, you *could* use, with caution, a *[String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence))*.
Note that, this will place an additional *space* character at the beginning, and end.
You can use, *[String#trim](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim())* to remove them.

```java
String string = new String(arr).replace("", " ").trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the approach I would take

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char arr[] = {'g', 'a', 'p', 'e', 't'};

    // Convert the char array to a string with spaces in between
    String result = String.join(" ", new String(arr).split(""));

    System.out.println("Array: " + result); // Output: g a p e t
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array of characters as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    char arr[] = {'g', 'a', 'p', 'e', 't'};

    for (char i : arr)
    {
      System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the StringJoiner do the work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char arr[] = {'g', 'a', 'p', 'e', 't'};
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
    for (char c : arr) {
        joiner.add(String.valueOf(c));
    }
    System.out.println(joiner.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation using basic Java. I've added a separate print statement at end to avoid space at the end of array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    char arr[] = {'g', 'a', 'p', 'e', 't'};

    for (int i=0; i<arr.size()-1; i++)
    {
      System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print(arr[arr.size()-1]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the loop, the `trim()` method is called on the resulting string to remove any trailing whitespace. Finally, the string is printed, resulting in the output: "Array: g a p e t".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char arr[] = { 'g', 'a', 'p', 'e', 't' };

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : arr) {
        sb.append(c).append(" ");
    }
    String result = sb.toString().trim();

    System.out.println("Array: " + result);
}
```